# How can I sort a ColdFusion query back and forth with a link?

Tags: sql, database, sorting, coldfusion, switch-statement

I have a ColdFusion page that displays data from a SQL database into a table. In the table header I have links set up to sort the data within its column. The problem is, I can only sort the data in one way: ascending or descending, depending on how I hard code it to act.

This is how I have my links set up (with the query set up to accept sorting):

```
<a href="mypage.cfm?sorter=numb ASC">Number</a>
```

What is an easy way to make it switch between ASC and DESC so if it is already sorted by ASC, then sort by DESC and vise versa?

Comment: I hope you're not putting #URL.sorter# directly in your query. That's a quick route to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the following:

```
<cfparam name="sortOrder" type="string" default="ASC">

<a href="mypage.cfm?sortColumn=numb&sortOrder=#iif(sortOrder eq "DESC", "'ASC'", "'DESC'"#">Number</a>
```

Comment: I mean iif. There was a typo (missing paren) in my snippet. It should be: '<a href="mypage.cfm?sortColumn=numb&sortOrder=#iif(sortOrder eq 'DESC', de('ASC'), de('DESC'))#">Number</a>'

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. Instead of ".cfm?sortColumn" I have ".cfm?sorter" because of my url.sorter defined up top.

Comment: It will work if you use 'ORDER BY #sortColumn# #sortOrder#' in your query. I think it's more robust to use these 2 separate parameters instead of the single "sorter" parameter. de() is the delay evaluation function and is required in this iif. You could use a normal if/else clause if preferred.

Comment: For the query I'd have

    <cfif IsDefined(url.sortColumn)>

?

Comment: OK, I finally got it working by using an if/else statement instead of the iif. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would define a default sortColumn as well: '<cfparam name="sortCoulmn" type="string" default="numb">'

Comment: @wahle509 - As Al Everett and rip747 said, using the url variables in a query are a recipe for sql injection. Be sure to scrub the values first.

Answer (score 2):

this is a little helper method i created that handles the swapping the sorting. to use just pass the name of the column to the helper within your link, the other argument are for customizing the helper:

```
<a href="mypage.cfm?sortby=numb&sortorder=#swapSortOrder('numb')#">Number</a>

<cffunction name="swapSortOrder" returntype="string">
<cfargument name="column" type="string" required="true">
<cfargument name="sortByParams" type="string" required="false" default="sortby">
<cfargument name="sortOrderParams" type="string" required="false" default="sortorder">
<cfargument name="ascending" type="string" required="false" default="asc">
<cfargument name="descending" type="string" required="false" default="desc">
<cfif
!StructKeyExists(url, arguments.sortByParams)
OR !StructKeyExists(url, arguments.sortOrderParams)
OR arguments.column NEQ url[arguments.sortByParams]
OR url[arguments.sortOrderParams] eq arguments.descending
>
<cfreturn arguments.ascending>
</cfif>
<cfreturn arguments.descending>
</cffunction>
```

Now i will tell you this, the way you're doing it currently with the column and order in one variable is **EXTREMELY** dangerous. i would strongly suggest you follow my link example and split the column and order into two variables.

why? it makes adding security very easy. on the page that the link throws to (in this case mypage.cfm) you need to filter the sortby and sortorder variables to prevent sql injection attacks.

what i normally do is create a list of known columns that people can sort by and then filter against it:

```
<cfset _columns="numb,title,name,phone,email">
<cfif !ListFindNoCase(_columns, url.sortby)>
  <cfset url.sortby = "title">
</cfif>
```

same goes for the sortorder:

```
<cfset _order = "asc,desc">
<cfif !ListFindNoCase(_order, url.sortorder)>
  <cfset url.sortorder = "asc">
</cfif>
```